# Failed to boot with newest kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.
After system update, I was prompted to reboot, but I chose to reboot later. However, due to a sudden power off, I didn't have the chance to reboot the system properly. Then comes the problem. I can't boot with the default newest kernel 4.13.0-39.

> Error message: " Failed to start load Kernel Modules"

But manually choosing an older version like 4.13.0-38 is ok.

Anyone can help fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Easy way

Run the command:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

It will fix anything it can that is broken. Anything it can't fix it will report to you which you can update into your question. If everything is OK next run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

You can wait until kernel `4.13.0-40` comes out. Simply use it and forget about `4.13.0-39` altogether. Just remember after booting `4.13.0-40` don't run `sudo apt autoremove` because then you will lose your working backup kernel `4.13.0-38`.

After you have both `4.13.0-40` and `4.13.0-41` installed you can run `sudo apt autoremove` to delete kernel `4.13.0-38` (and everything older).

---

### More complicated

You can also manually purge `4.13.0-39` ([How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)) and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-39
```